# method in MySQL to accept dates in custom formats

Tags: mysql

MySQL takes dates as `YYYY-M-D` for example if you do this :

```
  Select date("2012-9-6");
```

it will give :

```
  2012-09-06
```

but if you do this :

```
  Select date("6/9/2012");
```

it will give :

```
  null
```

now my question is :
is there a method in **MySQL** to accept dates in custom formats ??

something like :

```
  select date("6/9/2012","d/m/yyyy"); -- That gives : 2012-09-06 NOT null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '04/31/2004', '%m/%d/%Y' ) ;
```

This one works. But the order is month/day/year

More info in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Answer (score 0):

use the date_format() function

DATE_FORMAT("2012-9-6",'%m-%d-%Y')

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT("2012-9-6",'%m-%d-%Y');
+------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT("2012-9-6",'%m-%d-%Y') |
+------------------------------------+
| 09-06-2012                         |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

check this:

http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my question .. what I want is something like `select DATE_FORMAT("6/9/2012",'%m-%d-%Y');`